# Can't Get Aptana Studio 3 Autocomplete/Code Assist To Work?

Tags: php, autocomplete, aptana

Before you answer let me explain.  It works fine with local projects LOCALLY but not over FTP even with PHP class files are in the same directory.

For example if I have a file I'm including using require 'happyclass.php'; in my index.php file and I want to use a class that's in happyclass called happy I can do something like

```
$happy = new happy();
```

it will suggest the class and also autocompelte and auto-show PUBLIC METHODS AND FIELDS ETC OF THAT CLASS!

So for example say there was a public method called beHappy() in the happy class then when I did this

```
$happy->
```

The problem would still auto-show beHappy() as a public method of that class and suggest it.  All I have to do is press enter.

This works fine locally but NOT IF I'M USING THE CONNECTIONS MANAGER for FTP built into aptana.  My workaround has been using synchronization from local to remote but this is annoying and seems unnecessary.

What can I do?  Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: How would Aptana fetch information about files you haven't downloaded?  I think the proper and desired behavior is for Aptana to only index files you download... isn't it slow enough already? Imagine if it tried to index every file on your FTP server just because you made a connection.

Answer (score 0):

That how I get it to work:

create new project make sure PHP.
Right click on project icon.
PHP Buildpath - click add and choose folder witch all your classes.
OK
Bit lower Project Natures makes sure PHP is Primary;
OK

sometimes restart Aptana 3 and autocomplete working fine;